# Personal war stars - Do I get 3 stars added to my personal war star count if I attack a base that has already been 3 starred

Tags: clash-of-clans

So, some members of my clan have concerns on their personal war star count and do not like their bases being attacked before they get their first attack in.

My question is this. Say my mirror is 4. I get in and see that 4 is 3 starred before I get my first attack in. Most of the other bases in my range have been attacked too.

So I attack 4 again. I get 1/2/3/no stars. Assuming I get at least 1 star, does this add up on my war star count when I check my profile?

Answer (score 3):

In war, if you attack an enemy and you don't get 3 stars or if you don't get the desired stars to win, you cannot re-attack that enemy again for the duration of that war;However, all of the stars that YOU earn in war do go to your profile as war stars but you cannot get stars from someone that has already been 3 starred.

Comment: So make sure when you attack, you try your hardest to get 3 stars. ( as you only get 2 attacks per-war)

Answer (score 3):

I have just confirmed the answer to this question.

The answer is if a base has already been 1 or 2 or 3 star....and u got in and get 3 stars on that base....u will earn 3 stars on ur personal war star profile.

I had 200 personal war stars before my attack. I went to attack a base that's was already 1 star. I managed to 3 star that base.

When I went back to see my personal war star count it showed 203 war stars.

If u don't believe me try out an attack on a base that already has stars earned on.

Hope this answer helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you attack a base that has already been 3 starred, no matter how well you do, you will not earn any war stars. To earn war stars, they must be new stars. So if you attack a base that has zero stars and 3 star it, you will get 3 stars. If you attack a base that has 2 stars already, and you 3 star it, you will get 1 star, because 2 of the stars have already been earned.

Answer (score 0):

Nope, if a base has been 1 starred and you three star it you don't only get two stars for the profile you get the three stars added on, however only two star is given in the clan war

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if they used to give you the personal stars before but as of 2020 they surely don't .I attacked a base that had been 2 stared already and 2 stared it with a higher percentage, but my war stars remained the same. 
It's logically correct as well, your personal war stars count is the count of the stars you've contributed in wars so if you get them that would be counting them twice.
Hope this helps! :)

Answer (score -1):

Just discovered this and it is true. Say a base was 2⭐️ already and your clan has 30⭐️ total in the war. You attack and manage to get a 3 stars! After the attack, you will see that 3⭐️ were added to your personal profile. Your clan war total however will only be increased by one to 31⭐️ as there was already 2 stars done for that base.